# How can I make a custom module link appear on /admin/config?

Tags: routes, 9

I have a custom module I'm working on and I'd like to make it configurable via the admin menu. I'm having difficulty getting a form to appear in the admin page.

Visting admin/config/MYMODULE does show the form, it's just not visible on the /admin/config page.

Here is my file structure so far (excluding irrelevant files):

*The form file is just an example form to try to get it to appear on the admin page.

**MYMODULE.routing.yml**

```
MYMODULE.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/system/MYMODULE'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\myModuleSettingsForm'
    _title: 'myModule Settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

**MYMODULE.schema.yml**

```
MYMODULE.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'myModule Settings'
  mapping:
    path_to_sound:
      type: string
      label: 'Path to Sound'
```

**MYMODULE.links.menu.yml**

```
MYMODULE.settings:
  title: 'myModule Settings'
  description: 'Alter myModule Settings'
  route_name: MYMODULE.settings
  parent: system.admin_config_system
```

**MYMODULE.settings.yml**

```
path:
  path_to_sound: '/modules/custom/MYMODULE/myModule.mp3'
```

**myModuleSettingsForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Configure example settings for this site.
 */
class myModuleSettingsForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * Config settings.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const SETTINGS = 'MYMODULE.settings';

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'MYMODULE_admin_settings';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
    return [
      static::SETTINGS,
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config(static::SETTINGS);

    $form['example_thing'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Things'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('example_thing'),
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Retrieve the configuration.
    $this->configFactory->getEditable(static::SETTINGS)
      // Set the submitted configuration setting.
      ->set('example_thing', $form_state->getValue('example_thing'))
      // You can set multiple configurations at once by making
      // multiple calls to set().
      ->save();

    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
  }

}
```

It's my understanding that I should now be able to see this form on the config page, but I do not, regardless of cache clearing, etc. I followed documentation to do this and even cross referenced other popular modules, so I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To use `parent: system.admin_config` for a menu link it needs a route that has `_controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'` as a controller. And only now you can add children to that link.

`parent: system.admin_config` is for creating new thematic blocks. While you could use `parent: system.admin_config_content`, `parent: system.admin_config_system` etc. to add your link to an existing block.

So either switch `parent: system.admin_config` to `parent: system.admin_config_content` for example in your links Yaml and in your routing Yaml the path to `path: '/admin/config/content/MYMODULE'` to add your link to the "Content authoring" block.

Or adjust your MYMODULE.routing.yml and MYMDOULE.links.menu.yml to look like shown below instead to create a new thematic block and let your link be a child of that.

MYMODULE.routing.yml:

```yaml
MYMODULE.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/MYMODULE'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'MyModule'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'

MYMODULE.example_thing:
  path: '/admin/config/MYMODULE/example-thing'
    _form: '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\myModuleSettingsForm'
    _title: 'Example thing'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
```

MYMODULE.links.menu.yml

```yaml
MYMODULE.settings:
  title: 'MyModule'
  route_name: MYMODULE.settings
  parent: system.admin_config
  description: 'Configure MyModule'
  weight: -10

MYMODULE.example_thing:
  title: 'Example thing'
  parent: MYMODULE.settings
  description: 'Example thing configuration'
  weight: 0
  route_name: MYMODULE.example_thing
```

Comment: I understand and appreciate this answer, thank you. However, I tested adding it to an existing block, like system, doing as you said, and it still doesn't appear

Comment: @Joseph – If you switched to `parent: system.admin_config_system` in your links Yaml, switch to `path: '/admin/config/system/MYMODULE'` in your routing Yaml. Flush cache, of course, and if this still doesn't work, simply take a look at Drupal's code base, especially all the modules. There are plenty of examples of how you correctly put a link on the /admin/config page. For example https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.3.9/core/modules/system/system.routing.yml#L153-159 and https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.3.9/core/modules/system/system.links.menu.yml#L115-120.

Comment: I edited my question to change the links and routing files to what they are now which are almost identical copies of how it is done in the examples you provided, and it still won't appear. Am I missing something, or is there some other thing potentially preventing it from working?

Comment: `is there some other thing potentially preventing it from working?`  Can you reproduce module's issue on a fresh Drupal install, if not, then yeah something is preventing from working as it should @Joseph